# What does cv::mcc::CChecker::getChartsRGB() return?

Tags: c++, opencv, colors, rgb

In OpenCV, the [`cv::mcc::CChecker::getChartsRGB()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/db/d3e/classcv_1_1mcc_1_1CChecker.html#a9d9a2a30d0cb64dad12cf60bedae2563) method returns a `cv::Mat` object. What is the meaning of the values of the returned matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix returned by `getChartsRGB()` for a 6x4 color chart has shape `(72, 5)`.

At https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/4.8.0/modules/mcc/src/checker_detector.cpp#L1237 the meaning of the five columns is described as "p_size, average, stddev, max, min".

Each of the five columns contains for each of the 24 detected color chart cells 3 values.
In the first column ("p_size") the three values are the same for each cell, and they indicate the number of pixels in the detected cell.

In the remaining columns the three values indicate the red/green/blue components of the color value, giving the average color, the standard deviation, and the minimum and maximum color values.

For `getChartsYCbCr()` the same column order is used, but the three color values are the Y/Cr/Cb components of the color (according to https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/4.8.0/modules/mcc/src/checker_detector.cpp#L111).

It appears that the 24 color chart cells are always ordered in the same way (regardless of the orientation of the color chart): row by row (top to bottom), and inside each row from left to right. For the [standard 6x4 Macbeth chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ColorChecker) the list will therefore always start with "Dark skin" (#735244) and end with "Black" (#343434).